# King of Tokyo, effects of cards after monster death

Tags: king-of-tokyo

In King of Tokyo, when a monster dies does the effects of shrink counters or poison counters placed by that monster still apply, or do those counters fall away with the eliminated monster ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no rules that say effects that originated from a monster go away once that particular monster has perished, so they persist.

Other than being logical it saves on bookkeeping too, otherwise you'd need to track who gave you which counter because powers can be stolen and multiple monsters may have given you a counter from the same power...

Comment: There is actually a rule for the Poison Spit and Shrink Ray cards, on page 7 of the current King of Tokyo rulebook.  https://www.iello.fr/sites/default/files/2016-10/KingOfTokyo_2016_EN_Rules.pdf   It reads, "Poison and Shrink tokens stay in play and in effect even if Poison Spit or Shrink Ray leaves play..."  This clarification is also present in older editions at least going back to 2015 edition.  The current rules do clarify that a player's Keep cards are discarded when they are eliminated (page 4).

Answer (score 0):

We're not talking about an effect requiring ongoing effort (e.g. Killing Magneto would allow Wolverine to move again), we're talking about a permanent physical change (e.g. Killing a snake doesn't neutralized poison it previously injected into you).